# document is created if documentId is empty

Tags: xpages

I have a dominoDocument on my Xpage which gets a document from a database if a parameter is set (param.docId).
Unfortunately a document is created when the documentId results to empty (param.docId = ""). As Anonymous I am not allowed to create Documents. Therefore I get the yellow login screen.

```
<xp:dominoDocument
    var="contactData" action="openDocument">
    <xp:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dbEntryConfig:DatabaseEntry=getDatabase()}]]></xp:this.databaseName>
<xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:var docId = param.docId;
    if(docId != null){
        contactSaveData.replaceItemValue("contactDataDocId",docId);
    }else{
        docId = contactSaveData.getItemValueString("contactDataDocId");
    }
    return docId;}]]>
</xp:this.documentId>
</xp:dominoDocument>
```

Is there any way to prevent creating a document?

Answer (score 1):

By default all dominoDocument datasources will pull their settings from the URL parameters. If you're setting the `documentId`, you need to set `ignoreRequestParams="true"`, otherwise anything in the URL will override whatever you define there. Also, that will ensure `action="openDocument"` cannot be overridden by amending the URL.

Check any save button on the page as well. If it has `save="true"`, that means "save all datasources". Without `ignoreRequestParams="true"`, it may also be saving this datasource. The "Save Data Sources" simple action also saves all datasources on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Unfortunately ignoreRequestParams did not solve the problem. I still get the yellow login screen on page load.

Comment: It sounds like the user doesn't have access to the XPage / NSF (which could be either the NSF with the XPage design in it or the NSF with the data). If that's the case, it's nothing to do with having a datasource on the page that you code the ID for.